# how to create list within a list until condition

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a website and trying to return the data in a particular format:
My code:

```
for i in titles:                                                                                       
    title  = i.css('tr[class="bg_Sturm"] > td[class="hauptlink"]::text').get()                        
    if title is None:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        try:                                                                                                                                                                                              
            date = i.css('tr > td[class="erfolg_table_saison zentriert"] ::text ').get(default = "")  
            club = i.css('tr > td[class="no-border-links"]>a ::text ').get(default = "").strip()                                                                                                        
            if date or club:                                                               
                print({date:club})                                                                                                                                                                          
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):                                                            
            pass                                                                                      
    else:                                                                                             
        print(title)
```

My output:

```
2x Champions League participant
{'2021': 'Borussia Dortmund'}
{'2020': 'Red Bull Salzburg'}
1x German cup winner
{'20/21': 'Borussia Dortmund'}
2x Young player of the year
{'2020': ''}
{'2018': 'Eliteserien'}
1x German Bundesliga runner-up
{'19/20': 'Borussia Dortmund'}
3x Footballer of the Year
{'2021': 'Norway'}
{'2020': 'Norway'}
{'2019': 'Austria'}
2x Striker of the Year
{'21/22': 'Borussia Dortmund'}
{'20/21': 'Borussia Dortmund'}
1x Austrian cup winner
{'18/19': 'Red Bull Salzburg'}
3x Top scorer
{'20/21': 'UEFA Nations League B'}
{'20/21': 'UEFA Champions League'}
{'18/19': 'U-20 World Cup 2019'}
1x TM-Player of the season
{'2020': 'Austria'}
```

I want to make a list of dicts, such that after every title, a list of the following dates and the clubs. And to look like this:

```
[{"2x Champions League participant":[{"date": '2021':, "club": 'Borussia Dortmund', {"date":'2020':, "club": 'Red Bull Salzburg'}], 
{"1x German cup winner": [{"date":'20/21', "club": 'Borussia Dortmund'}],
"2x Young player of the year":[{"date":'2020', "club": ''},{"date":'2018', "club": 'Eliteserien'}]
```

and so on...

Comment: Declare `result = []`, then in `else` block declare `current = []` and append it `result.append({title: current})` and finally replace your `print` with `current.append({date: club})`.

Comment: I don't seem to follow. Where do I declare the print? Would you kindly show me in a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple task. From test output I assume that title always appears before data which belongs to this title, so basically you need to declare result list and append dict with `title` as key and empty list as value once title appeared and then add data as separate dictionaries to this list.

```py
result = []
for i in titles:                                                                                       
    title  = i.css('tr[class="bg_Sturm"] > td[class="hauptlink"]::text').get()                        
    if title is None:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        try:                                                                                                                                                                                              
            date = i.css('tr > td[class="erfolg_table_saison zentriert"] ::text ').get(default = "")  
            club = i.css('tr > td[class="no-border-links"]>a ::text ').get(default = "").strip()                                                                                                        
            if date or club:                                                               
                current.append({date: club})                                                                                                                                                                          
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):                                                            
            pass                                                                                      
    else:                                                                                             
        current = []
        result.append({title: current})
```